# Can we fetch values from a Jenkins Config file and use it as a parameter in a Jenkins Job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a config file created using the Config File Provider Plugin. The file contains values like

```
val1 = abc
val2 = def
val3 = ["abc","asd"]
val4 = ["abcd","asdf"]
```

I want to extract a value from the file, e.g. val3 and use it as a parameter to a Jenkins job. I would prefer if this was a multi-select option using a plugin like 'Extended Choice Parameter'.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I need to do the same thing but am having a hell of a time finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this.
Instead of creating a file using the config-file provider, I created the file on my Jenkins master.

Using the Extended Choice Parameter, under the "Groovy Script File" option, I gave the path to my file.

Answer (score 0):

With groovy script you can read the file, then readlines and select the lines you want to use.